# Why I need to use tf.global_variables_initializer() to initialize variables when I am using some pre trained model paramenters?

Tags: tensorflow

```py
def train_model(model, batch_gen, num_train_steps, weights_fld):
    saver = tf.train.Saver() # defaults to saving all variables - in this case embed_matrix, nce_weight, nce_bias

initial_step = 0
with tf.Session() as sess:
    **sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())**
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(os.path.dirname('checkpoints/checkpoint'))
    # if that checkpoint exists, restore from checkpoint
    ***if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)***
```

In the above codes it's very clear how ow graph try to import pretrained parameters if there are any.(highlighted section)
So if have already trained parameter set (for example weight set of a neural net) why we still have to initialize variables with **tf.global_variables_initializer()**?

Comment: I'm not sure that you do need to initialize global variables. At least I know that when you [restore the session from a metagraph](https://agray3.github.io/2016/11/29/Demystifying-Data-Input-to-TensorFlow-for-Deep-Learning.html), you do not have to, although you should throw in a `tf.reset_default_graph()` if you are working in a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **do not** have to use we tf.global_variables_initializer() if you use saver.restore(sess, file) before running any of the tensorflow graph.

Rewrite your code like so:

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:

    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(os.path.dirname('checkpoints/checkpoint'))

    # if that checkpoint exists, restore from checkpoint
    if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    else :
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

You can see a fully working example of [another example here](https://github.com/panchishin/learn-to-tensorflow/blob/master/solutions/06-save.py)

Comment: will this save memory ?

Comment: yes, like maybe 26 bytes of CPU memory. :)  Some would say that it will cut down on GPU and CPU, but it is outside of your main training loop or induction loop, so the savings in CPU/GPU computation are crazy small.

Comment: "You do not have to use we tf.global_variables_initializer() if you use saver.restore(sess, file) before running any of the tensorflow graph." Does this imply I have to initilize after running the graph but before restore? (this may happen in some very special scenarios)

Comment: Yes, if you run you graph, the variables in your graph have to have values.  The two ways discussed here are to either use the initialize function or the saver.restore function.